# CSS to style one line of text

Tags: css

I have a single line of text that looks like this:

> GIVE US A CALL AT ###.###.###

I want the phone number to be significantly bigger than the text and I want it all bottom aligned within the div.

I can't seem to get this to work... what I am missing?

Current HTML:

```
<div class="accessSlogan">
   <div class="access-slogan-text">GIVE US A CALL AT </div>
   <div class="access-slogan-number">###.###.###</div>
</div>
```

Current CSS:

```
.accessSlogan{
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    display: inline;
}

.access-slogan-text {
    display:inline;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    line-height: 2em;
    padding-right: 6px;
    vertical-align: text-bottom;
}

.access-slogan-number{
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    display:inline;
    font-size: 1.8em;
    line-height: 2em;
    vertical-align: text-bottom;
}
```

Comment: like this? http://jsfiddle.net/kjy112/sEYTc/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `<strong>` tag and style accordingly.

```
<div class="accessSlogan">
   GIVE US A CALL AT <strong>###.###.###</strong>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.accessSlogan{
   float: right;
}

.accessSlogan strong {
    font-size: 1.8em;
    position:relative;
    bottom:0.4em;
}
```

The point is to use the existing "semantic" HTML to work with you and avoiding over-complicating things.  The `<strong>` tag is what you mean,  so use it:-)

The relative position of the strong text will need to be adjusted to align perfectly. 0.4em is a starting point (half of the extra height),  but it depends upon the size of the accessSlogan text.

Comment: I would argue `<strong>` isn't semantically correct here at all, just because it is to be displayed bold or in larger text doesn't indicate stronger importance. Also, if you're really talking semantics then why is the container still a `<div>`?

Comment: You're right;  probably changing it to something like: 
<p class="accessSlogan">
   Give us a call at <span>###.###.###</span>
</p>
would be more appropriate (and less afflicted with divitus).

Answer (score 1):

Both your markup and CSS seem over-complicated, although without knowing where this is to be positioned on a page it's hard to know if that's necessary or not.

At it's simplest this will achieve it:

```
.access-slogan {
    float: right;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.access-slogan .access-slogan-number {
    font-size: 1.8em;
}

<p class="access-slogan">Give us a call at <span class="access-slogan-number>###.###.###</span></p>
```

Note that you can't apply `float` and `display:inline` to an element since `float` applies `display:block` along with it's own document flow rules. You'll also note I've uppercased the text in CSS rather than in the source HTML, since this is a display artefact.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a much more minimal set of CSS you can use for this. Is this [demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/7DNUQ/) what you were after?

Answer (score 0):

use `<span>` instead of `<div>`. It will solve your problem

```
<div>
 call me at <span>0000-000</span>
</div>
```

or

```
<div>
 <span>call me at</span><span>0000-000</span>
</div>
```

Comment: The problem is in relation to the CSS, this will solve nothing since the elements have either `display:none` or `float:right` applied